# How to Use CodePipeline with multiple projects

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

my current solution has two projects in it. It has a .net core WebAPI and a class.  I was successfully able to create a buildspec file and my code pipeline builds

Folder structure currently

```
Dockerfile
net-core
    -> net-core.api
       -> buildspec.yml
    -> net-core.nuget
```

buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
      - REPOSITORY_URI=$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/net-core
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
      - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
      - echo Writing image definitions file...
      - printf '[{"name":"%s","imageUri":"%s"}]' "net-core-container" "xxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/net-core:latest" > net-core-imagedefinitions.json

artifacts:
  files:
    - net-core-imagedefinitions.json
```

The issue I currently face is now I want to pack net-core.nuget and publish it to codeartifact repository. How do I tell buildspec to look at a certain project within the repository so it knows which to pack https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/using-nuget-packages-in-codebuild.html